# How to delete last comma in multiple select in r Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm using R shiny tools and I meet a problem. When I use the multiple select button, I want to add a comma at the end of every selections,here is what I do:

UI.R

```
conditionalPanel("input.Select_Table == 'Demographics'",
               selectInput(inputId ="demo",label ="select variables you need", multiple = TRUE,
                             choices=c('Respondent_ID','year','month','City','City_Level','Province',
                             'Region','Actual_Age','Age_Level','Household_Income','Personal_Income_Level')))
```

Server.R

```
output$demo <- renderText(paste(substring(input$Select_Table,1,1),".",input$demo,","))
```

the output would be like this:

```
D . City , D . year , D . Province ,
```

however,I don't want the last comma at the end of last selection(the one behind"D . Province ,"), but so far I haven't find a way to delete it automatically. Could you please help me?

Thanks a lot,

Verse

Comment: try `renderText(paste(substring(input$Select_Table,1,1),".",input$demo, sep = ","))` ?

Comment: @Dee Will add a weird double comma as such `,.,` and im not too sure why. That was what my first though was.

Comment: @Dee change to `renderText(paste(substring(input$Select_Table,1,1),".",input$demo, collapse = " , "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didnt provide the `input.select_table` just the `conditionalPanel` I have tweaked the code to get a working example. You basically want to change the last part of the `paste` function to be `collapse= " , "`. Note the space around the comma, that is to get the same formatting as you provided. As such:

```
## ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(

selectInput(inputId ="demo",label ="select variables you need", multiple = TRUE,
                                choices=c('Respondent_ID','year','month','City','City_Level','Province',
                                        'Region','Actual_Age','Age_Level','Household_Income','Personal_Income_Level')),


mainPanel(
  textOutput("demo")
)
))



## server.R

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$demo <- renderText(paste("D"," .",input$demo, collapse = " , "))
})
```

I used `"D"` instead of your `substring(input$Select_Table,1,1)` as that wasnt provided in the OP.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your contribution, but I'm looking for a way to remove the last comma other than replace the 'D'.

Comment: @Versehe read my answer. you didnt provide the ability to create the `input` `select_table` so I had to subsitute. The `D` was simply an example. Provide the `input` otherwise. The answer you want is in the `collapse` argument of  the `paste` function. With that it will add a `,` between each element given to `paste`. You currently add the comma as an argument, not the separator, hence why it will always add the last comma.

Comment: @ amwill04 , sorry I just realized that. I followed your step and it works well now, thank you very much, you really help me well.